# Any way to display PDF in browser full screen

Tags: html, pdf

When displaying a PDF with standard (US letter) size pages, the PDF appears to be 'zoomed out' in Chrome. In Firefox, the PDF shows at a better zoom level.

Here is an example:
http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
When viewed in Chrome on a 4k monitor, it is zoomed out so far that you can see 1.5 pages. While in Firefox you can see roughly half of the first page which in our case is much more desirable.

Is there any way that we can display this PDF at a standard zoom. For example, setting some headers, etc.

I'm currently using PHP to display the PDF, by setting the following headers and then echoing out the file.

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great!!

Comment: Do you mean at 100%? Or so it just fills the browser window vertically, regardless of window size? Because a true full screen view that hides the browser chrome would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the description above
Chrome was and still does generally use ***"standard" 100% zoom***.
Whilst FireFox was using Fit Width (***"roughly half of the first page"***).

Many  pdf extenders but not all will use the Adobe Acrobat URL trailing fragment so for the example in question try

http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf#zoom=200

however that can be fickle and require a second refresh of same URL.

Better (for more consistency) with the questions description of Firefox at the time use.

http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf#view=FitH

Which for me, with my current window in Chromium Brave / Edge will be 136% on this occasion, but some other 100%hv on a different window setting or screen.

Note the above can be over-ridden as much HTML can by the clients setting so assuming they allow a PDF to run with its own control, it works but if they pre-set remember last PDF view setting it may not.